# Дата в 4-х байтах

Tags: qt4, c++

Дата 25.03.2012 представлена в виде D137AB02. Что за алгоритм? Как из Hex-числа получить эту дату?

Comment: А можно ещё хотя бы одну дату увидеть.Спроси на rsdn.ru, там любят такие задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Это число секунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1901 года.

D137AB02 = 3 510 086 402 секунд. При переводе в дату учитывайте високосные года.